# uiActionSheet init failing in a CCLayer

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, uiactionsheet

Environment: ios; iPad; cocos2d

I have a cocos2d CCLayer derived class in which I'm trying to bring up a UIActionSheet to verify a "quit game" request by the user. The code to bring the UIActionSheet up is as follows:

```
UIActionSheet *verifyQuit = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit Game ?" 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitle:nil];
[verifyQuit showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[verifyQuit release];
```

On the init (the first line in my sample), I get the error logged to the debugger console:

-[UIActionSheet initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x54cb10

The init never returns, and the error is logged repeatedly until I stop the program from the debugger. I don't know what the object is at the address 0x54cb10 - it is not the CCLayer-derived object from which I'm trying to instantiate the UIActionSheet.

Any ideas on what I'm running into here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a small thing you are missing.

```
otherButtonTitle:nil
```

Should be

```
otherButtonTitles:nil
```

There's an ***s*** missing at the end of the argument name - thus the compiler cannot find that method.

Comment: Ah, now I feel stupid. Thanks, Man. I went over it and over it; I guess I had tunnel vision.